# Java, output continually being output on same line

Tags: java, constructor, while-loop, println

The problem that I am having with this program is that when a user has entered in the camera brand name followed by the number of pixels, the program starts put putting both the brand name and pixel request on one line. I simply want the program to output and input the same throughout the program!

This is probably a simply problem; however, it is confusing me.

This is the class file:

```
public class DigitalCamera {

public String brand;
public int megaPixels;
public int price;

DigitalCamera( String receivedBrand, int pixelsReceived) {
    brand = receivedBrand;
    if (pixelsReceived >= 10)
        megaPixels = 10;
    if (megaPixels <= 6)
        price = 99;
    else
        price = 129;
}

public void returnDigitalCameraDetails() {
    System.out.println("You ordered a " + brand + " camera with " + megaPixels + " megapixels at a cost of $" + price);
    }
}
```

This is the main file:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestDigitalCamera {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String cameraName;
int pixelsForCamera;
int x = 1;

    while (x <= 5) {

System.out.println("Enter in brand of the camera: ");
    cameraName = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter in the number of pixels: ");
    pixelsForCamera =  scan.nextInt();
DigitalCamera camera(x) = new DigitalCamera(cameraName, pixelsForCamera);
camera(x).returnDigitalCameraDetails();
System.out.println();
x++;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by you "want the program to output and input the same throughout the program"? What output are you getting and what is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
cameraName = scan.nextLine();
```

by:

```
cameraName = scan.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String cameraName;
    int pixelsForCamera;
    int x = 1;

    while (x <= 5) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter in brand of the camera: ");
        cameraName = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter in the number of pixels: ");
        pixelsForCamera = scan.nextInt();
        DigitalCamera camera = new DigitalCamera(cameraName, pixelsForCamera);
        camera.returnDigitalCameraDetails();
        System.out.println();
        x++;
    }
}
```